# Get CGRect from NSStringFromCGRect

Tags: objective-c, frame, cgrect, cgrectmake

I stored a frame (`CGRect`) in a `NSStringFromCGRect`, how do I later retrieve the rect?

```
[mDict setObject:NSStringFromCGRect(frame) forKey:@"frame"];
```

I need to get the data back how?

```
CGRect frame = [[mDict objectForKey:@"frame"] ..?]
```

Does a method exist or I have to parse the string manually?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for,

```
CGRect frame = CGRectFromString([mDict objectForKey:@"frame"]);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `NSValue` instead of creating a string representation.
`NSValue` instances are objects and can be put into a dictionary

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithRect:(NSRect)frame];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"frame" : value};

CGRect frameBack = (CGRect)[dict[@"frame"] rectValue];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(frameBack));
```

If you need a string representation which is easily reversible, you could use this

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100., 100.0);
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithRect:(NSRect)frame];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
NSString *base64String = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String);

NSData *dataBack = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:base64String];
NSValue *valueBack = (NSValue *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataBack];
CGRect frameBack = (CGRect)[valueBack rectValue];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(frameBack));
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to store the data (CGRect) as a string so I can encrypt it,   NSValue is not a String. Thank you for your attempt!

Comment: `NSValue` adopts `NSCoding`. You could create an `NSData` object and encrypt this

Comment: Thank you, but I needed a String not an NSData Object. Much appreciated for your quick response!

Comment: I updated the post to provide a solution with `NSValue` to get a string

Answer (score 0):

Until someone find a better solution this is what I came up with:

```
-(CGRect) CGRectFromNStringFromCGRect: (NSString *) string {
    NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
    newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
    newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSArray *array = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if ([array count]==4) {
        return CGRectMake([array[0] floatValue], [array[1] floatValue], [array[2] floatValue], [array[3] floatValue]);
    } else {
        return CGRectZero;
    }
}
```

Use Like this:

```
CGRect frame = [self CGRectFromNStringFromCGRect:[mDict objectForKey:@"frame"];
```